# XCode forgetting SVN user's password?

Tags: xcode, permissions

Every time I try to connect to my SVN server via XCode, it won't connect and I need to re-enter my password (and only my password) for the SVN user. I know that nobody else has to do this, and that this forgetful nature is probably because I screwed up permissions big time about a month ago (I took permissions of every file on the harddrive. Stupid, I know). Other applications have exhibited this behavior if the permissions on the plist files were still messed up and the behavior was fixed as soon as I deleted the plist file. I've looked as much as I can for a plist file pertaining to SCM user settings in XCode so I can delete it and have XCode create another with proper permissions but I can't find this plist anywhere. There may not be a plist at all, is there any other file that, with bad permissions, would cause the SVN user's password to be repeatedly forgotten? If it is a plist, where is it?

I've already checked ~/Library/Preferences and inside XCode.app. I see no plist relating to my problem.

I should also mention it's Snow Leopard running XCode 3.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist?

Comment: It doesn't seem so. I don't have a ~/.MacOSX folder, nevertheless any files inside it.

Comment: You have to enable hidden system files: http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/04/show-hidden-files.html

Comment: I tried going there through the Terminal, I used "ls -a" and still didn't see it. I know that the dot makes it a hidden folder, but I don't seem to have that folder.

Comment: Does deleteing /Library/Preferences/com.apple.xCode not solve the prooblem?

Comment: Deleted it before, oddly enough XCode never recreated that plist. But it has had no impact on the SCM settings or their behavior.

Comment: I've also tried ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.xcode and it forgot the SCM server altogether, but when I put in all my information, connect, then exit (force quit) xcode it goes back to the way things were: remembering everything except the password. Could this be a problem with the keyring?

Comment: Yah. You should try resetting the keyring.

Comment: It would be in the .ssh folder. Perhaps generate a new key.

Comment: Where would the .ssh folder be? It's not in my home directory

Comment: Thats strange. On most systems (Windows/Unix) it should just be at ~/.ssh

Comment: It's not in my home or my root... I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: try deleting .subversion is home.